# SSRS grouping chart by parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, reporting

I have problem with grouping by parameter in my chart.

Let's assume query that gives data like below:

[image]

I would like to Group category in the cart based on parameter.
Parameter has value City or Country but it can be also different (no possibility to define constant list)
On the chart I should see (based on parameter):

Parameter: City

[image]

Parameter: Country

[image]

Is there any possibility to do it in SSRS?

Comment: update your question and add  text data sample   and not image (only)  ,,

Comment: Do not include any links! Always include your sample in your question as `formatted text`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your parameter has values of 0 and 1 where 0=Country and 1=City....
You just need to set the following items

- The cell to be displayed ( in column 1 in your example)
- The `Group On` expression of your row group
- The `Sort by` expression of your row group

to the same expression, something like this...

```
=IIF(Parameters!groupColumn.Value =0, Fields!country.Value, Fields!city.Value)
```

Its the exact same expression in all three places.

If you can't get this working, let me know and I'll post an example but it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do use an expression for `group by`:

```
select (case when parameter = 'City' then city
             when parameter = 'Country' then country
        end) as which,
       sum(value)
from t
group by (case when parameter = 'City' then city
               when parameter = 'Country' then country
          end);
```

That said, I think you should have separate queries in SSRS for the different values.  Such parameterized queries are harder to optimize and harder to maintain.